# CSS file linked with HTML is not working when uploaded on free hosting server

Tags: html, css

My css file is linked with my HTML and working fine on my computer but it is not working on the free host website as only text is displayed but not images and styling

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description" content="Website designing page- to design Professional website">
      <meta name="keywords" content="Webdesign, Website design, Web designing, web developer, 
      Webdeveloper, Webdesigning websitedesign">
      <meta name="robots" content="nofollow, noindex">
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="author" content="Nishant Saxena">
      <title>Nivasha- Web Designing Solutions</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ The usual problem with a web page not connecting with CSS is the folder _ You have `style.css` in a folder `CSS` on your local machine BUT do you have the same folder setup on the live version?

Comment: I have exactly entered into the same format on the hosting website with the CSS and image folder onto the public_html folder. But its not working.

Comment: So that we're clear _ you have created a 'CSS' folder inside the 'public_html' folder?

Comment: yeah... I have uploaded CSS folder onto public_html folder of my webspace onto the free hosting website.

Comment: ok thanks _ have you tried just putting `style.css` in the same folder as your HTML file _ and changing the link reference accordingly = `href="style.css"` ?

Comment: if you have the html file in the public folder and a subfolder "css" (lowercase) with the file "style.css" (lowercase) inside it, then it's a problem with the server, nothing to fix in the code.

Comment: have you tried my idea of placing the CSS file in 'public_html' and changing the link as suggested?

Comment: Thanks Alex... I have exactly the same name of the folder as described in the code.

Comment: Done the same @input but of now use :(

Comment: Wait! got it. Thanks alex.  The name of the CSS folder was in caps, I converted into lowercase and it worked. :)

Comment: Thanks @inputforcolor for giving time for my code. :)

Comment: so it was a folder problem then ; ) Good Luck @NishantSaxena